# SonarQube dependencies not found for sonar-findbugs-plugin

Tags: sonarqube, findbugs

I receive error `Dependency META-INF/lib/bcel-findbugs-6.0.jar can not be found in sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.0.jar` during build on jenkins for all projects using sonarqube:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) @ tig-parent ---
[INFO] SonarQube version: 4.4
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /opt/jenkins/workspace/TIG nightly sonar/target/sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.4
[INFO] [16:54:50.855] Load global settings
[INFO] [16:54:51.042] User cache: /var/run/tomcat/jenkins-master-dev.mycompany.com_00/.sonar/cache
[INFO] [16:54:51.055] Install plugins
[ERROR] Dependency META-INF/lib/bcel-findbugs-6.0.jar can not be found in sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.0.jar`
```

I am not aware of any changes in project sonar configuration, jenkins or sonarqube server. I checked that `sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.0.jar` plugin contains `bcel-findbugs-6.0.jar` library. I reinstalled the findbugs plugin without effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to delete sonar cache: `/var/run/tomcat/jenkins-master-dev.mycompany.com_00/.sonar/cache`

Answer (score 0):

. You mean that it did work before but it does not work anymore?
. When you say that you are not aware of any changes in configuration, you mean there has not been any upgrade of software?
. No modification in your environment (Java version, path, etc.)

Comment: Exactly. I am not aware any changes in SonarQube. And it started to fail for all projects with same error.